# Finding button with Splinter

Tags: javascript, css, selenium, web-scraping, splinter

There is a sign in button but im not able to find its name on the source page.
The url of the web page is http://pict.ethdigitalcampus.com/PICT/

Which method of splinter could i use here?

```
        <td width="214" colspan ="2"><div align="left">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In" onclick="return validate();" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; border: 1px solid #666666; padding-left: 2; padding-right: 2; padding-top: 1; padding-bottom: 1">
           <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" style="font-family: Verdana; font-size: 8pt; border: 1px solid #666666; padding-left: 2; padding-right: 2; padding-top: 1; padding-bottom: 1">
          <br>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on Murali's answer, xpaths are useful in this scenario.

```
import splinter

browser = splinter.Browser()
browser.visit("http://pict.ethdigitalcampus.com/PICT/")

button = browser.find_by_xpath("//input[@value='Sign In']")
```

The "//" at the beginning of the xpath allows you to find input elements in any part of the document, to keep the query generic.

Answer (score 2):

If name is not available, known id, class also not provided. so you can try with cssselector or xpath

```
cssSelector=input[value='Sign In']
xpath=//input[@value='Sign In']
```

Thank You,
Murali